# Can I set a window.name in JS, so that later from another page, I can user <a target='name'>?

Tags: javascript, html

In one window of, e.g. foo.example.com:

`<script>window.name='HERE';</script>`

Then in another window, later, e.g. bar.example.com:

`<a href='foo.example.com' target='HERE'>GOFOO</a>`

Does this work? Is there a way to get back to a window that was not initially named with a `target=''`?

Comment: Did you try? Did you get errors? You likely will only succeed if both windows are from same origin

Comment: > Modern browsers will reset Window.name to an empty string if a tab loads a page from a different domain

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Answer (score -1):

The window.name property can indeed be set in JavaScript. However, it does not work exactly like the way you're envisioning.

In HTML, the `target` attribute of the `<a>` element is used to specify where to open the linked document. The values for this attribute can be:

`_blank`: Opens the linked document in a new window or tab.
`_self`: Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default).
`_parent`: Opens the linked document in the parent frame.
`_top`: Opens the linked document in the full body of the window.
framename: Opens the linked document in a named frame.
So the value of `target` attribute is interpreted as a frame name, not as `window.name`. They are not directly linked.

However, `window.name` does play a role in cross-window communication. When you navigate from one page to another, the `window.name` persists (even when navigating across domains), until the window or tab is closed, or until the window or tab navigates to a page on a different domain that clears `window.name`. But it does not work in the way you are trying to use it in your example.

It is important to note that `window.name` property is mainly used for scripting and not designed as a way to reference windows across pages via `<a>` tags.

What you're trying to accomplish – referencing an existing window/tab from another window/tab – is generally not directly possible due to the restrictions posed by the same-origin policy and limitations on inter-window communication for security reasons.

However, you could use other approaches such as using `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, or `postMessage` for some forms of inter-window or inter-tab communication, depending on your exact needs.

Comment: According to MDN

> The name of the window is used primarily for setting targets for hyperlinks and forms.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: Why post a ChatGPT generated answer?